# Обновление приложения (получение apk с сервера)

Tags: java, android

Задался вопросом о том, как обновить приложение? Насколько мне известно, если телефон не рутирован, то только через Установщик пакетов с согласием пользователя. Так вот, суть такова:

На сервере лежит apk файл с новой версией приложения. Нужно скачать этот apk файл на телефон в директорию приложения (чтобы не запрашивать разрешение на доступ к файлам устройства), после успешного скачивания сразу же открыть установщик приложений с этим apk файлом.

Как это можно вообще сделать? Именно возникла проблема на этапе сохранения, как это сделать?

Comment: а установщик приложений типа потом сам все сделает?

Comment: передать через интент ему apk файл, и открыть. А пользователь потом соглашается от установки или отказывается.

Comment: ну так если пользователся все равно спрашивать, то почему бы просто не сказать ему, чтобы нажал на ссылку для скачивания апк и сделал все сам?

Comment: Нужно пользователя "пнуть", ведь некоторые вообще не понимают, или не хотят. Я слышал, что это действие можно на половину автоматизировать.